# Profiler for MSAccess

Tags: ms-access, profiler, sql-server-profiler

I have a MSAccess .mdb file backed with sql server.
When i am trying to open a form ,It takes a long time to display
I know i had stuff on load event of Form.

Is there any way to track execution time in MSAccess like SQL Profiler?

Answer (score 2):

Faheem;
I have never seen such tracking software.

A simple, 'old school' method:
 Place a msgBox at the end of each function call.
 Once you have isolated which function is running longer than expected, examine the  function. Are your recordsets utilizing indexed fields? Avoid opening multiple recordsets simultaneously. Are you minimizing the use of Loops? Are your loops optimized?

Another thing to check is the use of Access macros to calculate Aggregates (sums, averages).
This causes Access to run individual queries repeatedly. If you had a situation where you were dealing with more than 100,000 records and 2 dozen columns, the Access macros would fire 2 dozen times(once for each column).

Using the methods outlined above I have taken a good-sized DB Warehouse app (.25 million records in main Data table, 40 columns) and streamlined reports taking an hour to process down to 5 seconds. The client was very happy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by "I know I had stuff on load event of form". Can you not check the macros/VBA attached to your form? What things are you doing on load?

- Do you have multiple subforms within your form? I have experienced long open/load times when using forms with multiple subforms. Especially when the subforms pull a small subset of data from a very large record source.

Check this link out:
http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/204374-timer-function-determining-code-execution-speed

```
Dim sngStart As Single
Dim sngEnd As Single
Dim sngElapsed As Single
Dim time As Single

sngStart = Timer ' Get start time


'your code here

sngEnd = Timer 'get stop time
sngElapsed = sngEnd - sngStart

time = Format(sngElapsed, "######0.0000000000")
MsgBox "Time elapsed: " & time, vbInformation, "Time Elapsed"
```

Comment: thanks for the link and code. It is good.Actually i needed a **software** that will track each and every statement/query/command while running things in MSAccess. In sql server we can view each detail in Sql Profiler. It shows complete detail of things from start to end.

Comment: Since you are connected to SQL Server, run the profiler, and it will show each and every query/reply to the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function timeGetTime _
Lib "winmm.dll" () As Long
Private mlngStartTime As Long

Private Function ElapsedTime() As Long
ElapsedTime = timeGetTime() - mlngStartTime
End Function

Private Sub StartTime()
mlngStartTime = timeGetTime()
End Sub

Public Function MyTest()

Call StartTime
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1"
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataQuery, "Query1", acLast

Debug.Print ElapsedTime() & _

Call StartTime
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query2"
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataQuery, "Query2", acLast

Debug.Print ElapsedTime() & _
End Function
```

[See Here](http://www.microsoft-questions.com/microsoft/Access/36314175/how-to-measure-query-performance.aspx)

Also, check your form design. Are there a lot of subforms / Master/Child links? How much aggregation is there? Etc.