# Table adapter fill issue

Tags: vb.net

I have an interesting issue with filling table adapters that may make some of you scratch your heads.

I have a windows application that has several forms that load depending on the users decisions on where they want to go. The very first form opens when the app is started and fills the table adapter on form load. (As per the way the designer sets it all up for you) Keep in mind every form uses the same table adapter with the one table being used if it needs it. The same Binding Source is also used for all forms and therefore each form will have different datasets and table adapters as required. When the first form loads it loads reasonably fast even though the table adapter fill loads just under 3500 records. The databases (2 of them) get updated only 3 times a week with less than 10 records for all DB's so the databases don't grow very fast. So the databases used when filling table adapters remains the same for the most part so load time wouldn't change much over time.

Now the first form is loaded and table adapter is filled so the user goes to a different form ... the new form again fills the table adapter on load and takes maybe even less time to display after the fill. (Granted it is a smaller form) From that form there is another form that can be loaded and when that one loads it takes at least 10 seconds or more to display that form because of the table adapter fill on form load. It doesn't matter where I put the fill statement on that form. I had it so the fill did not occur until the user clicked a button to select records instead of in the form load and it still takes the same longer time to fill than when the 1st form and 2nd form load up. I thought maybe it was because I disposed of the table adapter on the last form before opening the 3rd form but I looked and I didn't dispose of it. So I'm stumped as to why on this 3rd form that the fill takes so much longer than the 1st two forms filling the adapter.

Any ideas ???

Comment: Have u used SQL Profiler to see what is occurring when the third form loads with the table adapter... This will provide some insight as to whether it is SQL where the slowness is occurring or whether it is the application/binding.

Comment: Ah thanks for that pointer. I'm not sure exactly if I have such a thing. Currently I am using VB2015 but I'll google SQL profiler and see whats what. Actually this is first time I have heard of it but then I'm still really new to .NET format.

Comment: Hmmm ... problem, I don't have SQL Server (any version) and VB2015 doesn't have a profiler. Guess I'm SOL.

Comment: Where does your data come from? It will have a database of some sort.

Comment: Data comes from a MS Access 03 file. The first two forms load fast and the 3rd form loads exactly the same way codewise but it takes about 5 to 7 seconds longer for some reason. I thought it might be the form itself having more stuff to load and draw but if I fill the table adapter after the form loads the form instantly displays no problem. So I'm totllay stumped here.

Comment: Yes, the data comes from the same DB same table same for all 3 forms.

Comment: If your application connects to a database using ODBC and a registered data connection):

In Administrative Tools (Control Panel or even Start Menu if they are displayed), you can find an "Data sources (ODBC)" applet. Start it and click on "Tracing" tab. Voila!

Comment: Not sure if this link would help with tracing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971550.aspx

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316166/profiler-for-msaccess

Comment: One other option is to link the MS Access tables to SQL instead of having inside MS Access... Download SQL Express install it and recreate the tables and then use Access Linked tables to connect: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-A5A3B4EB-57B9-45A0-B732-77BC6089B84E?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1